# Django-Geopostion default value error

Tags: python, django, google-maps, django-geoposition

I'm trying to integrate Django-Geoposition package into my Django project. I have my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    position = GeopositionField(default= Geoposition(40.00,73.88))
    votes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    sound= models.FileField()
```

I've tried leaving no value for position, but I can't make migrations without a default value. I've also gone ahead and removed all instances of the model from the admin. Even with what I have above (which I found from another person with the same issue) I'm getting a
 `AttributeError: 'Geoposition' object has no attribute 'split'` 
when I try to make the migration. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I used blank=true so that I didn't have to put in a default value